# Validate Z-score Formula

Tags: sample-size, validation, z-score

I need need help validating a formula for a z-score. I have a book that I enjoy but in my re-read of the materials, I have found that the author has made some fundamental errors in their writing. So, I want to validate the author's approach to generating a z-score before I use it:

**Z = [observed result - mean expected result] / standard-deviation**

He defines standard deviation as:

**sd = probability of result * square root of the number of trials**

So for predicting coin flips, if a coin came up heads 52 times in 100 trials he would write:

**z = [52 - 50] / (0.5 * sqr(100))**

Does that look right to anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The z-score is computed as

$$x_i' = \frac{x_i - \mu}{\sigma}$$

Where $\mu$ is the population mean, $\sigma$ the standard deviation of the population, and $x_i$ a single observation.

The standard deviation for the binomial distribution is $\sigma=\sqrt{n p(1-p)}$, so it sounds correct to me what is in the book. Assuming the $0.5$ you have defined is the probability, you have $\sqrt{100 \times p \times (1-p)}$, which is $\sqrt{100 \times 0.5 \times (1-0.5)}$ with $p=0.5$, i.e., $\sigma = 0.5 \times \sqrt{100}$.

(This is assuming that it's a z-score involving normal approximation.)